# Use docker with fastapi and redis

Tags: docker, redis, fastapi

I would like to build and run a docker image from a Python code using fastapi and redis. To do this, I have already coded my API in Python with fastapi and redis, and installed docker as well as docker-compose. But then, I do not manage to integrate redis in my docker image (it is the first time I try to create a docker image).

I managed to understand how to use Python in a docker container and add fastapi to the docker contained, but for uvicorn and redis, it seems harder and I did not understand.

More precisely, the terminal indicated : "Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:80 (Press CTRL+C to quit)" but when I went to the link https://0.0.0.0/ , I got an error in my web browser ("Unable to connect").

And, for integrating redis, I'm lost.

Here is my Python code (called "main.py") :

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from redis import StrictRedis


app = FastAPI()

#Products are identified by name, so there cannot be two products with the same
#name !
redis_data = StrictRedis(host="localhost", port=6379, db=0)
products = {}
for key in redis_data.scan_iter():
    products[key.decode("utf-8")] = eval(redis_data.get(key))


@app.get("/")
async def get_product_information(product_name: str=""):
    """
    product is the name of the product about which we want information (quantity
    and price).
    Returns a dictionary indicating the price and the quantity disponible of the
    product.
    If product is an empty string, then returns the dictionary containing
    information for every referenced product.
    If the product in not referenced, then returns a message error.
    """
    if product_name == "":
        return products
    if product_name in products.keys():
        return products[product_name]
    return "Error : None of the referenced products has the specified name"

@app.post("/")
async def add_product(product: dict):
    """
    Adds a product to the database. The product is representend by a dictionary
    with tree items :
        one indicating the name (key : "name", value : the product's name) ;
        one indicating the price (key : "price", value the price) ;
        one indicating the quantity (key : "quantity", value : the quantity).
    """
    product = product.copy()
    for feature in ("name", "quantity", "price"):
        if not feature in product.keys():
            return f"Error : The product should have a {feature}."
    product_name = product.pop("name")
    products[product_name] = product
    redis_data.set(product_name.encode("utf-8"), str(product).encode("utf-8"))
    return "The product has been added."

@app.delete("/")
async def remove_product(product_name: str):
    """
    Removes the product product from the database.
    """
    if product_name in products.keys():
        del products[product_name]
        redis_data.delete(product_name)
        return "The product has been removed."
    return "Error : None of the referenced products has the specified name."
```

Here is the content of my dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.9


# Any working directory can be chosen as per choice like '/' or '/home' etc
# I have chosen /usr/app/src
WORKDIR /usr/app/src

#To COPY the remote file at working directory in container
COPY main.py ./
COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

#CMD instruction should be used to run the software
#contained by the image, along with any arguments.
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

This is the content of the file "requirements.txt" :

```
fastapi
uvicorn
```

Can you help me please ?

Thanks in advance,

Good evening !

Comment: you need to do some reading ... https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/docker/ might be a good place to start

Comment: What's the specific problem you're running into?  The one obvious thing I can see from the code is that the hard-coded `localhost` Redis address is probably wrong in a Docker context.  Can you [edit] the question to explain more about what you're trying to do and what's going wrong?

Comment: Okay, I will edit my question, thank you.

Comment: I did some reading and edited the question. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you need to account for when starting your Docker container, is the port mapping.
You are telling fastapi to listen on port 80:

```
#CMD instruction should be used to run the software
#contained by the image, along with any arguments.
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

But, docker itself will expose it via a port mapping, meaning it will take that port 80 *inside* the container and expose it on some other port on your local host, like 8080.

See also [Docker's own documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/):
`-p 8080:80 Map port 8080 on the Docker host to TCP port 80 in the container.`

If you are using Docker compose you could do something like:

```
myfastapi:
    image: myfastapi
    ports:
      - 8080:80
```

Like in [their documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)